# Is there a way to define a new directory for files in Oracle

Tags: javascript, angular, oracle, oracle-apex, subdirectory

When using Angular the output creates files in folders such as "dist", "src", etc.

Is there a way in Apex 4.1 to tell the system to look for and use files within sub-directories [inside the images folder?]?

Reason being, I want to create a Dashboard App in Apex 4.1 that integrates an Angular App built using node.

So build the App using Node.js and Angular, then output to Production.

Then take those output files (HTML, CSS, JS) and incorporate them into an Apex 4.1 Theme that uses Oracle database to populate widgets in the dashboard.

This has been easy when using jQuery mobile, but getting Angular to work has been an issue so far due to the directory structure of the output files.

I have been able to get the `<body ng-app="app">` code into the `<body>` tag, just haven't figured out how to tell Apex to use a new folder path in the theme editor.

So far all I can do is use `#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#` and call files within the images folder:

```
<script src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.js"></script>
```

I need to be able to call files like this:

```
<script src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#/dist/index.html"></script>
<script src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#/src/index.html"></script>
```

etc. etc., which doesn't work.

Older versions of Angular seem to create only one output folder: src; and inside that folder is only one .html file, one .css file and one .js file.

Newer angular versions don't seem to support one folder with all the files in it?

Comment: What do you mean, it "doesn't work"? When you use something like `#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#/dist/index.html`, and view the page with your F12 developer tools, does an error message appear? Also, what are you hoping will happen when you call an HTML file using a `script` tag? Have you tried an `iframe` instead?

Comment: Errors on the 3 JS files in folders in the images folder:

The script from “http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/apex/wwv_flow_file_mgr.get_file?p_security_group_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&p_fname=demo/main/script.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

Comment: So it loads them, but throws an error.

Here is code I am using:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#dist/angular-gridster.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#demo/common/style.css" />
<script src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#src/angular-gridster.js"></script>
<script src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#demo/main/script.js"></script>
<script src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#demo/dashboard/script.js"></script>

Comment: Also, When I view source, then try to open the css and js files above, none of the .js or .css files have any code in them; it seems like they are loading, but none of the code is coming through.

Comment: If you copy one of the full URLs it's trying to load (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/yourImageDir/src/angular-gridster.js` and browse to it directly, can you view the file? If yes, it's loading fine but your page isn't using it. If no, probably your URL is wrong.

Comment: Yes. This is the path that worked: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/wwv_flow_file_mgr.get_file?p_security_group_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&p_fname=icons-18-white.png' in the CSS file.

Comment: Oh - so the `WORKSPACE_IMAGES` substitution string points to files which have been uploaded into the database under Shared Components. If you want to access the files in the images dir on the filesystem, try using `#IMAGE_PREFIX#` instead. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#BEIGJJBG

Comment: It also requires you to alter the DAD configuration to add a new directory path: https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_epg_10gR2